# How to get the X and Y position of the dial in a seekbar

Tags: android

I need to get the X and Y position of the "thumb" of a seekbar.

Calling `seekbar.getThumb().getBounds()` returns me a bound that is relative to the seekbar.

Is there a way I can get the position of the thumb that's relative to the whole screen?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, not quite sure what to do with the 5 there. Minus 5 is exactly the center of the x position of the dial.

```
// tipBar is the seekbar.
int [] location = new int[2];
tipBar.getLocationInWindow(location);
int x = location[0] + tipBar.getThumb().getBounds().centerX() + tipBar.getThumbOffset() - 5; // magic 5
int y = location[1] + tipBar.getThumb().getBounds().centerY();
```

Comment: this may help you , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451838/get-onscreen-position-of-current-seekbar-progress-secondary-progress